# Path error calling test from a function in python

Tags: python, django

[image]

I have a functional test 'gtest.py' which I am trying to call from within a python/django function. I am trying to follow the GIST at https://gist.github.com/santiycr/4274570. Inside the calling function I have:

```
import unittest
import ft/gtest
unittest.main(module=ft/gtest.py)
```

The last 2 lines are are giving syntax errors as I type them into the pycharm IDE, so I suspect the path is wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import ft.gtest
```

is what you need to do ... `ft/gtest` is division between two variables that dont exist

(likewise you would pass `ft.gtest` to the module argument of `unittest.main`

you could also do

```
from ft import gtest
```

or

```
from ft import gtest as g
```

or

```
import ft.gtest as g
```